# Angular runtime created components aren't listed in @ViewChildren

Tags: angular

As you can see in this example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-knbzcs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) Angular doesn't seam to list runtime created components (via `viewContainerRef.createComponent(HelloComponent)`) in it's `@ViewChildren(HelloComponent)`.

Is this an expected behavior or a bug? Do I need to mark it somehow so it get's listed?

Edit: just updated the example. Sorry, was a broken version so no chance to comprehend! As you can see now, the dynamic components aren't counted.

Comment: helloCount is 1, what am i missing here?

Comment: Yes, it is one. But that's just the static one! No dynamics are counted.

Answer (score 0):

in general a QueryList is mannaged subscribing to changes observables, some like

```
  @ViewChildren(HelloComponent) helloComponents:QueryList<HelloComponent>

  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    this.helloComponents.changes.pipe(startWith(null)).subscribe(res=>{
      this.helloCount=this.helloComponents.length
    })
  }
```

NOTE: I use the rxjs/operator startWith to allow at first execute the action.